# Change ng-model before submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple model that submits a form that are all from a `select` I am using an `ng-repeat` like so:

```
 'Ctrl'
 isdom.scheduleOptions = ['Pass', 'N/A'];
 'html'
 <select ng-model="isdom.isdomForm.isDom101">
   <option ng-repeat="option in isdom.scheduleOptions" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
 </select>
```

The person who has built the `api end point` is asking for the data in this format:

```
"outcomes": [
     { "itemNo": "is11", "outcome": "Pass" }
     ,
     { "itemNo": "is12", "outcome": "Pass" }...
```

How can I do this when my model is like so?

```
{
 "isDom11": "N/A",
 "isDOm12": "Pass",...
}
```

I thought about try to get all the elements in the model that start with `isDom` and pushing them into an `outcomes` array that has been modified into objects to copy the format required.

Is there a different way I can use ng-repeat to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ng-options` for populating the `select`.

See: [ngOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) or [select](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/select)

So it should be something like this:

```js
$scope.isdom.scheduleOptions = [
     { "itemNo": "is11", "outcome": "N/A" }
     ,
     { "itemNo": "is12", "outcome": "Pass" }
  ];
```

```html
<select ng-model="isdom.isdomForm.isDom101"
        ng-options="item as item.outcome for item in isdom.scheduleOptions track by item.itemNo"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `(key, value)` syntax as given in angular docs.

[Key value in ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

**(key, value) in expression –**
 where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

```
For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.
```

Your example,

```
isdom.scheduleOptions = {
                "isDom11": "N/A",
                "isDOm12": "Pass",...
                }


<select ng-model="isdom.outcomes">
   <option ng-repeat="(itemNo, outcome) in isdom.scheduleOptions" value="{{outcome}}">{{outcome}}</option>
 </select>
```